# Shell Script: How to write a string to file and to stdout on console?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, sh, ksh

How to write a string to file and to `stdout` on console?

If I do

```
echo "hello" > logfile.txt
```

I view only `hello` in `logfile.txt` but how can I write `hello` also on console of Linux?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Use the [`tee`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tee.html) command:

```
echo "hello" | tee logfile.txt
```

Comment: You can also do `tee logfile.txt <<<"hello"`

Comment: Just FYI `echo` adds newline character to the output file.
If you don't want it use `printf` command it only writes the string to file and will not append newline character

Comment: Or you can use `echo -n`

Answer (score 47):

You can use `>>` to print in another file.

```
echo "hello" >> logfile.txt
```