# In shell script how to print command to file and show the command as well?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have multiple `ls -l` commands in my shell script and i want each line to append it's output to text file so i run it like this:

```
ls -l /directory/to/check/exists >> validation.log
```

The file will show only the output but I also want it to show the command that was executed.
How can I have this without adding both command and `echo` of same command to avoid multiple lines?

Thank you

Comment: The `tee` command is your friend.  [Documentation](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/tee.2.html).  Additionally, refer to [this Unix & Linux SE question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80707).

Comment: Do you want the _output_ of `ls` in both the file and STDOUT, or do you want the file to contain, literally, `ls -l /directory/to/check/exists`? If it’s the former then see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22713667/418066), if the latter then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78119052/418066) is a duplicate (but virtually unanswered).

Comment: As per @Biffen's remark, you can use `set -o xtrace` to have commands echoed to STDOUT as they are being executed.

Comment: I tried with tee , and with  >>, nothing i do works, each time i get an output file that only has the output result and not showing the command itself. unless i'm doing echo which i'm trying to avoid ..

Comment: same result with set -o xtrace or set -x. it shows me what i need on the screen but inside the output file i see only output not command..

Comment: Ah, you need the command **and** the command output to be both stored in your file? Then try redirecting STDOUT to STDIN like this : `set -o xtrace; ls -l /directory/to/check/exists >> validation.log 2>&1`

Comment: Do [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66950971/1765658) your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bash function:

```
run() {
    echo "$@"
    "$@"
}

run ls -l /directory/to/check/exists >> validation.log
```

It has the advantage to let you format the command as you like, eg `echo ">> $@"`.